# laravel how to use star rating plugin on a form text input

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My project is on storing reviews on products. I am using Laravel framework here. The review has a field for rating the product. I am using the jquery 'starrr' plugin for the rating.

Form :

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'/admin/reviews', 'role' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('title', "Title:", ['class'=>'control-label col-md-2']) !!}
<div class="col-md-8">
{!! Form::text('title', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('product_id', "Product:", ['class'=>'control-label col-md-2']) !!}
<div class="col-md-8">
{!! Form::select('product_id', $products, null, ['class'=>'form-control product_list'])!!}
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('rating', "Rating:", ['class'=>'control-label col-md-2']) !!}
<div class="starrr"></div>
{!! Form::hidden('rating', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!} 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
{!! Form::button('<i class = "fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add New Review', ['type' => 'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-lg']) !!}
</div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

controller store method:

```
public function store(Request $request){
$rules = [
            'product_id' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
];
$this->validate($request, $rules);
create($request->all());
return redirect('admin/reviews')->withSuccess('Review is created');
}
```

My question is how to get the rating value from the star rating, into the request object to store on the database?
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.starrr').starrr({
  change: function(e, value){
    $('input[name="value"]').val(value)
  }
})
```

This will set the input to the value of the `starrr` plugin whenever it is changed.  Then the input value will be sent to the server

Comment: thanks Jeff. Tried your suggestion, but did not succeed. rev_rating is the name field. $('input[rev_rating="value"]').val(value) keeps returning default value of 3.